# Debugging a running python process

Tags: python, remote-debugging

Is there a way to see a stacktrace of what various threads are doing inside a python process?

Let's suppose I have a thread which allows me some sort of remote access to the process.

Answer (score 6):

[Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) is a **platform independent** graphical GPL Python debugger with support for remote debugging over a network, multiple threads, namespace modification, embedded debugging, encrypted communication and is up to 20 times faster than pdb.

Features:

- GPL license. Winpdb is Free Software.
- Compatible with CPython 2.3 through 2.6 and Python 3000
- Compatible with wxPython 2.6 through 2.8
- Platform independent, and tested on Ubuntu Gutsy and Windows XP.
- User Interfaces: rpdb2 is console based, while winpdb requires wxPython 2.6 or later.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [winpdb.org](http://winpdb.org/images/screenshot_winpdb_small.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Without any guidance on how to use the product to select and control threads, and without any indication on the user's part that they are even using Windows, this sounds suspiciously like a bullet-pointed advertisement.

Comment: @Brandorn: It is not windows-only. It is multiplatform as I clearly stated on the answer, in bold face. The screenshot shows clearly how you can debug threads.

Answer (score 2):

About 4 years ago, when I was using twisted, manhole was a great way to do what you're asking.

http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/telnet.html

Right now most of my projects don't use twisted, so I just WingIDE's remote debugging hooks to introspect a running process.

http://www.wingware.com/doc/debug/remote-debugging